# MathJax fraction rendering issue with zoomed page

Tags: latex, markdown, ipython, mathjax

I'm rendering the following line in a markdown cell in an IPython notebook (OS 10.8.2, Google Chrome browser):

```
$$\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = f(x)$$
```

At the normal zoom level, it looks like this

[image: normal_zoom]

I'm trying to use this in a webcast and want to apply zoom to the screen

> Blockquote

. At the zoom level I want, the fraction rendering gets ugly.

[image: zoomed_in]

Is there a way to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome, but there is a work-around in MathJax v2.1.  I suspect you are using an earlier version, so if you update that, it should resolve your problem.

Comment: IPython.external.mathjax.install_mathjax installs version 1.1 be default. I used `install_mathjax(tag='v2.1', replace=True)` and `%reload_extension sympy_printing`. Safari still displays correctly, but Chrome shows a Math error. :-(

Comment: WHen you obtain a new version of MathJax, you usually have to clear the cache and restart your browser in order to get the new version (restarting is important, particularly in Chrome) otherwise part of MathJax may be cached older versions.  Try clearing the cache and restarting the browser.

Comment: That solved it. I had to restart the browser, not merely reload the page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Does not seem to be an IPython issue, I can reproduce it here : 
http://util.io/mathjax
with {\partial \over \partial x}g(x)
Is it just to have the math bigeer or the all page ? You can try to change the zoom factor of equation in mathjax option/right click. Notebook server does not yet expose configuration for that though.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. I did not know about the right-click menu.

Answer (score 1):

The issue only exists in Google Chrome. It renders properly in Safari:

[image: big_zoom, properly rendered]